# Calculation of correlation coefficient

Tags: c#, image-processing, correlation, aforge, accord.net

In this research article, in the section [4.3.1 (core detection)](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/50282799_Multidirectional_Scratch_Detection_and_Restoration_in_Digitized_Old_Images),

[image]

**How can I calculate correlation coefficients between two pixels?**

```
    public static Complex[,] Correlation(Complex[,]image, Complex[,]mask)
    {
        Complex[,] convolve = null;

        int imageWidth = image.GetLength(0);
        int imageHeight = image.GetLength(1);

        int maskWidth = mask.GetLength(0);
        int maskeHeight = mask.GetLength(1);

        if (imageWidth == maskWidth && imageHeight == maskeHeight)
        {
            FourierTransform ftForImage = new FourierTransform(image); ftForImage.ForwardFFT();
            FourierTransform ftForMask = new FourierTransform(mask); ftForMask.ForwardFFT();

            Complex[,] fftImage = ftForImage.FourierImageComplex;                
            Complex[,] fftKernel = ftForMask.FourierImageComplex;

            Complex[,] fftConvolved = new Complex[imageWidth, imageHeight];


            for (int j = 0; j < imageHeight; j++)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < imageWidth; i++)
                {
                    fftConvolved[i,j] = Complex.Conjugate(fftImage[i,j]) * fftKernel[i,j];
                }
            }

            FourierTransform ftForConv = new FourierTransform();

            ftForConv.InverseFFT(fftConvolved);

            convolve = ftForConv.GrayscaleImageComplex;

            Rescale(convolve);

            convolve = FourierShifter.FFTShift(convolve);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("padding needed");
        }

        return convolve;
    }
```

**Is this the correct procedure to [calculate correlations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-correlation#Properties)?**

If yes, how can I find Correlation-coefficients from that?

Comment: The correlation is not between two pixels but between two neighborhoods around the pixels.

Comment: @AmitayNachmani, do `Correlation`, `Correlation Matching` and `Cross-correlation` represent same stuffs? That is, the multiplication of complex conjugates? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-correlation#Properties

Comment: i am not an expert in those things but crooss-correlation measures the correlation between two signals for different amount of shifts. Each value of cross correlation ( which is a vector) is a correlation measured  for a specific shift.

Answer (score 2):

In article correlation are calculated between two "windows", i.e. between two sets of points, not between two points. if i'm not mistaken, correlation coefficient is a scalar value, not a vector. In signal processing , correlation calculated as sum of multiplications divided by sum of squares of signal values. It may be incorrect in details, but in general, correlation calculated like this:

```
correlation = sum(S1[i]*S2[i])/sqrt(sum(S1[i]^2 * S2[i]^2));
```

For 2-dimention case (window) just add second index:

```
correlation = sum(S1[i,j]*S2[i,j])/sqrt(sum(S1[i,j]^2 * S2[i,j]^2));
```

Comment: What are `S1` and `S2` here?

Comment: S1 and S2 are two sets of values. It can be values of signal or values of picture pixels. In your case, S1 and S are "two windows" in this quote from your article: "(ii) cg is the “global” correlation value, computed between two windows, centered, respectively, in the starting point pr and in the candidate point pi of the column k"